Postgres use recursive CTE to find the root node
I have seen and read many posts on using a recursive CTE to get the hierarchy from a self-related table.
I want to get just the root node of an entry in my table. In other words, if I have a suburb called Brooklyn, I want to return North America from the hierarchy (bottom-up): Brooklyn -> New York City -> NY -> USA -> North America.
In fact, just the id of the row North America.
I am not sure where to put filter for Brooklyn and how to just get the root node.

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

with recursive dat as (
    select id,
           parent_id
      from Location_table
     where id = :Id_Brooklyn 
     --
     union distinct
     --
    select a.id,
           a.parent_id
      from Location_table as a
      join dat as b on b.parent_id = a.id
)
select id
  from dat
  where parent_id is null;

